# jquery menu slideup too slow?

Tags: jquery

I have an li menu I'm using that when a div is hovered over a sub menu slides down on the right side. Then when the div is no longer being hovered it slides up as you would expect. However there seems to be an issue where if the mouse hovers to another div while the last one is still sliding up, then the last one will not finish closing and 2 sub menus will be open. If I move the mouse slowly or change the slideup speed to 0, then it works, but I'd like to have the sliding animation if I can.

Here's the hover function:

```
  $(listitem).hover(

  function () {

    listID = $(this).find("ul");
        $(listID).slideDown('medium',function() {
    $(this).clearQueue();
});

     }, 
     function () {
    listID = $(this).find("ul");
        $(listID).slideUp(0,function() {
    $(this).clearQueue();
});

     } );
```

);

http://mayaincaaztec.com/

Instead of posting a jfiddle, u can look at the site I'm working on. If a jfiddle is needed, I'll throw one up. If you hover over the tab "Maya Inca Aztec Agriculture" a side menu will come down. The next 3 tabs will also do this. If you move the mouse quickly from one tab to the next, the previous one will remain open. Thats what I'd like to fix

Comment: I think a (not) working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be awesome :) , so we can see whats going wrong and (maybe) fix the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll post a jfiddle when I get it running..

Comment: Is there really a `'medium'` duration on jquery? last time I checked the valid duration strings are `'slow'` and `'fast'`. Other than that (or random string value) jquery will give it a default 400ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the call to `slideDown()` is made before `slideUp()` finishes, the call to `clearQueue()` removes `slideDown()` from the queue, so the element remains visible. What you want to do is stop an animation before you start the next one, like this:

```
$(listitem).hover(function () {
    $($(this).find("ul")).stop().slideDown('medium');
}, function () {
    $($(this).find("ul")).stop().slideUp(0);
});
```

But if you really want `slideUp(0)`, you could just as well use `.hide()`.

Comment: I had actually discovered this moments before your post! .stop solved the issue. thanks anyway ;)